# Retrive endpoint url of deployed app from google cloud run with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-run

I want to send requests to a deployed app on a cloud run with python, but inside the test file, I don't want to hardcode the endpoint; how can I get the URL of the deployed app with python script inside the test file so that I can send requests to that URL?

Comment: There are multiple methods (CLI, SDK, REST API). Edit your question to clarify by what method. You will have to hardcode something - either the service URL or the service name. You are trading one small problem for a larger task and adding authorization as a dependency.

Comment: You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76588695/2263683)

Answer (score 3):

In a pure Python way, you can use Google's API Client Library for [Run](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/run_v1.html).

To my knowledge, there isn't a [Cloud Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference)

The method is [`namespaces.services.get`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/run_v1.namespaces.services.html#get) and it is documented by APIs Explorer [namespaces.services.get](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get).

One important fact with Cloud Run is that the API endpoint differs by Cloud Run region.

See [service endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest#rest_endpoints). You will need to override the client configuration (using `ClientOptions`) with the correct (region-specific) `api_endpoint`.

The following is from-memory! I've not run this code but it **should** be (nearly) correct:

```py
import google.auth
import os

from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions

creds, project = google.auth.default()

REGION = os.getenv("REGION")
SERVICE = os.getenv("SERVICE")

# Must override the default run.googleapis.com endpoint
# with region-specific endpoint
api_endpoint = "https://{region}-run.googleapis.com".format(
    region=REGION
)

options = ClientOptions(
    api_endpoint=api_endpoint
)

service = discovery.build("run", "v1", 
    client_options=options,
    credentials=creds
)

name = "namespaces/{namespace}/services/{service}".format(
    namespace=project,
    service=SERVICE
)
rqst = service.namespaces().services().get(name=name)
resp = rqst.execute()
```

The `resp` will be [Service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services#Service) and you can grab its [ServiceStatus](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services#ServiceStatus) url.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gcloud to fetch the url of the service like this

> gcloud run services describe  SERVICE_NAME
> --format="value(status.url)"